# Write a validation routine for a C# class on change event

Tags: c#, class, events

I'm trying to write an "onchange" event for a C# class that I have.  The idea would be to capture anytime the class was instantiated or a property was changed and fire off some code to evaluate the "health" of the object, then set a property of the class to true or false based off of the method being invoked.  My initial attempts were to simply call a private method in the setter of each property as such:

```
string _source = null;
public string Source
{
    set 
    { 
        this._source = value;
        OnClassChange();
    }
    get { return this._source; }
}

string _dest = null;
public string Dest
{
    set 
    { 
        this._dest = value;
        OnClassChange();
    }
    get { return this._dest; }
}

bool _isValid;
public bool IsValid
{
    get { return _isValid; }
}

void OnClassChange()
{
    _isValid = (_source == null) ? false : true ;
    _isValid = (_dest == null) ? false : true;
}
```

but this seems sort of clunky and not elegant... I'd like to use some sort of listener, then in my OnClassChange() block simply loop through all the private properties of the class, determine the type of property and invoke some logic to determine if the values of the property is valid or not in a loop.

Comment: Aside from anything else, your validity *only* depends on `_dest`. I suspect you really mean: `_isValid = _dest != null && _source != null;`

Comment: Why should the change of one property care about the other properties? Is your event going to be listened for outside of this class? The way you have it set up right now, it isn't an event, it's just a private method.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment (sorry kinda new to practicing OOP), my thought process is basically that I need to instantiate an empty object using a default constructor, then while my main code runs properties of the empty object will get populated.  Since the validity rules are always the same for this class I wanted to essentially make it so that objects of my class can validate themselves.  That way, no matter where my object is in the main flow of my code, I can always call IsValid to determine if the object is complete or not.  At least that was my plan :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need a field for this at all - unless the validation is costly (so you want to avoid recomputing it each time it's requested) you can just have:

```
public string Source { get; set; }
public string Destination { get; set; }

public bool IsValid { get { return Source != null && Destination != null; } }
```

In C# 6 the `IsValid` code would be be even simpler:

```
public bool IsValid => Source != null && Destination != null;
```

Comment: Wow, that was remarkably easy.. I'm glad I asked.. thank you so much for helping me with this approach.